# Highlight image map area on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

```
<img src="images/QA_for_StreamingMedia_schema.png" alt="" usemap="#Map" hidefocus="true" />

<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="Applications" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applicationsPopUp" shape="poly" coords="163,341,275,275,384,340,368,361,341,380,316,393,296,398,277,400,247,398,213,386,178,362,164,345" />
<area alt="" title="Media" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mediaPopUp" shape="poly" coords="264,129,265,260,154,325,144,307,139,281,138,254,145,220,163,186,177,167,208,146,225,136,246,130,260,130" />

</map>
```

My code to map area. I want to highlight area onmouse over. I tried some css solutions but they wont work.

Comment: can you share your css ?

Comment: map:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: I think you are targeting the `map` using that `css` better give it like `map > area:hover { background: yellow; }`. this will only change the background of `area`

Comment: I want to fill colour

Comment: did that didn't do the work